# Is it possible to define an arithmetical hierarchy w.r.t. implication?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, first-order-logic, computability

Looking at how the arithmetical hierarchy classifies formulas based on alternating sequences of quantifiers, I am wondering if a similar classification can be defined in a language where we limit ourselves to $\bot, \to, \forall$, as is usually the case in axiomatic presentations. Does such a hierarchy exist?

I have tried looking up implicational hierarchy, but all results seem to relate to a concept in linguistics.